# Using a cut-off node in SAS after a HP Model

Tags: sas, enterprise-miner

I am having the following problem. We have a SAS Enterprise miner project with several model. Some are "normal" and some are HP. We are using a cutoff node after the models. Now if the node is being used after a "normal" node than everything is find, but if we try to use it after a HP node, the cutoff node is not working anymore.

Anyone have seen this? Anyone has any idea?

Thanks in advance, Umberto

Answer (score 0):

We have found a kind of solution. Our binary variables contained two strings. Once we changed the two strings to 0 and 1 the cutoff node started working. Now is strange since if we change the values to 'A1' and 'A2' (for example) it still works. Only for some specific strings is not working.

I would consider this a workout but maybe can save some time to others finding the same problem.